# binding a json cell value using parseJson function with its matching data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with one column contains json style value in it, and I am able to parse it with function called parseJson to return a table. But I am confused on how to bind the result with other tables.

```
table1
OrderDate   OrderNo   Weight   Cost   JsonProperty
11/01/2018  1234      8        10     {"JsonData":{"OrderNo":"1234","Shipper":"Andrew"}}
11/05/2018  2345      11       19     {"JsonData":{"OrderNo":"2345","Shipper":"Bell"}}

parseJson((select top 1  JsonProperty FROM table1 where OrderNo = '1234'))
element_id  sequenceNo  parent_ID   Object_ID   NAME        StringValue     ValueType
1           0           1           NULL        OrderNo     1234            string
2           0           1           NULL        Shipper     Andrew          null

Expected result table
OrderDate   OrderNo   Weight   Cost   Shipper
11/01/2018  1234      8        10     Andrew
11/05/2018  2345      11       19     Bell
```

My thought now is should I loop through all of the JsonProperty and create a new temp table using pivot first? If so how do I achieve that? I know how to do the pivot but how do I create a table with all the OrderNo from table1, assuming there are more than 2 items.

Comment: ParseJson looks like a custom function? Have you tried built-in OPENJSON function?

Comment: I believe that would return a similar table, but I am not sure what's the next step

Comment: It will provide [key] which is kind of a row number, so you can join it back to original table

Comment: yeah but it still only returns a single table contains info from one single cell of JsonProperty. How do I run through all of it and link back to table1?

Comment: Pivot parsed data on NAME field and then join this table by OrderNo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering your question:

```
SELECT t.OrderDate,t.OrderNo,t.Weight,t.Cost,a.Shipper
FROM table1 t
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT p.OrderNo,p.Shipper
    FROM (SELECT NAME,StringValue FROM ParsedDataTable) d
    PIVOT(MAX(d.StringValue) FOR d.NAME IN ([OrderNo],[Shipper])) p
) a ON a.OrderNo = t.OrderNo
;
```

**Better and simpler solution:**

```
SELECT t.OrderDate,t.OrderNo,t.Weight,t.Cost
   ,JSON_VALUE(t.JsonProperty,'$.JsonData.Shipper') AS [Shipper]
FROM table1 t
```

Comment: Thanks! My brain was just stuck and couldn't figure out where to put that pivot table and how to condition the where.

Answer (score 0):

I still had issue with the script since later I realized I need a WHERE inside the parser function, so I end up using cursor which solved my problem.